# AjaXplorer - Users from server

Tags: ajax, authentication, file-manager, pydio

I discovered AjaXplorer and I was wondering if I could set up an account system so that it uses the logins from the server it connects to.

If AjaXplorer is unable to do this, were could I find an alternative that could?

Comment: Do you mean using windows users if it exists on a windows server instead of the built in Ajaxplorer users, I am interested in that too.  Looking to see if it can use Basic authentication or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ajaxplorer could use external authentication from your system.

The article [5. Bridging AjaXplorer authentication with another application](http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/developer-documentation/chapter-external-bridge/) contains a  full explanation with example for the process.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it. Just follow the below url ...
http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/developer-documentation/chapter-external-bridge/